# Ionic 4 refresh tab page every time I enter

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular-routing, ionic4

I am using tabs and cannot refresh the page every time I re-enter the page. I am using ionic 4 so I cannot use navController.

I have used `ionViewWillEnter()` to display data from database in my app and it works but every time I go to another page and come back to the page, it will repeat the data. (for example I am displaying 5 data from firebase. When I go to another page and re-enter the page, it displays 10(repeating the same data) then 15, 20, 25... so on).

food.page.html

```
<ion-list  *ngIf="showFood">
    <ion-row *ngFor='let FoodFruit of showTypeOfFood("fruit")'>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-card>
                <div class="card-title">{{FoodFruit.wtitle}}</div>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-list>
```

food.page.ts

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.currentUser = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;

    if(this.currentUser == null){
     this.showFood = false;
    }
    else{
      this.showPersonalFood();
    }
}

showPersonalFood(){
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
    (user)=>{
      if(user){
        this.showFood = true;

    this.afDatabase.object('foods/').snapshotChanges().subscribe(
      (action)=>{
            if(action.payload.val())
            {
              console.log(action.payload.val());
              let items: any = action.payload.val();
              items.forEach(
                (food) =>{
                  this.foods.push(food);
                }
              );
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("No Data");
            }
          });
      }
    }
  );

}
```

```
showTypeOfFood(type)
  {
    let items:any = [];
    this.foods.forEach((Food)=>{
      if(Food.wtype == type)
      {
        items.push(Food);

      }
    });
    return items;
    }
```

Here, showTypeOfFood is just a function to display data from firebase.
So, it perfectly shows the data in food tab page, but it just won't refresh/ clear cache or delete previous data.. How do I achieve this?

Comment: so where is that method showTypeOfFood? can you share it? also why not just init all the values on page enter?

Comment: I've added it but it is not important at all. I just need to know how to REFRESH the page every time I enter. Even If I put those code into `ngOnInit`, it gives me the same result. it does NOT refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Ionic doesn't go well with refreshing pages. And if you ask to Ionic creators, it's not a bug but a feature...

But their is ways to bypass that:

## The "do exacty what you ask for but you should not do that" way

Give an attribute to your page that change everytime you go in (like the timestamp) so Ionic is forced to update the page by treating it like a new one.

**Why you shouldn't do that:**

If you do that, you will overload your memory and your app may crash

## The "technically you don't refresh the page, just the data, but it do the job" way

First, do everything in the ionViewDidEnter() (so everything will be done when you trully enter the page).

Then you have to:

- Declare an attribute:

```
export class VisionnagePage implements OnInit{ 
    public YourVar = [];//you access it with this.YourVar
    constructor(){};
}
```

- empty the global variable when you enter the page
- put items in this var.
- Read it (like you were reading `showTypeOfFood("fruit")`)

Comment: So I've declared `foodTpyeItems: any = [];` and added `this.foodTpyeItems = [];` in `ionViewWillEnter()` and my app just freezes and it will show blank page.. is there a reason?

Comment: what is the error messages?      And I think you should declare foodTpyeItems like this: foodTpyeItems: any []; and put it in ionViewDidEnter() (so it will be execute only when you enter the page) and not in ionViewWillEnter() (where it will be execute everytime you may go on this page, even if you don't (like if you navigate on any page))

Comment: I changed it to `foodTpyeItems: any [];` without `=` and RIGHT BEFORE `this.showPersonalFood();`, I have added: `this.foodTpyeItems = [];` in `ionViewDidEnter()` (please refer to food.page.ts). Also, in my `showTypeOfFood(type)` function, instead of items I used `foodTpyeItems`. BUT my app freezes and it won't even show the error message..

Comment: have you made some change before doing what I suggest to you? because I think it might go from that (maybe calling a library you forgot to install via npm for exemple)

Comment: No I haven't.. Do I need to npm install something for emptying array? because displaying contents from firebase works perfectly. But it would just keep appending the same content whenever I go back to the page..

Comment: No you don't need something to empty an array. however there is something that go wrong in your page, but I don't know what it is.

the bug go only when you are in the food.page.ts, or is it all the app that is break?

Comment: it only breaks when I add `this.foodTpyeItems = [];` in ` food.page.ts` and in ` food.page.ts` in the app

Comment: Where do you put this.foodTpyeItems = [] ? Because if you don't put it in a function (like IonViewDidEnter()), that normal

Comment: I put it in `ionViewDidEnter()` and it broke my app ONLY when I attempt to enter food page

Comment: well, at least their is something new. Still no error messages?